# Add handler to list box for when user opens list box?

Tags: javascript, events, gwt, listbox, dom-events

How do I add a handler to when a user just clicks on a list box but doesn't actually select anything?  As far as I can tell, onclick on fires when the user selects an item in the dropdown and not when they actually click on it to see the options.

(Bonus points if you know how to do this in GWT instead of just raw javascript).

Thanks!

Comment: listbox? you mean a regular select HTML element?

Comment: yes (sorry its called a ListBox in GWT)

Answer (score 1):

mmm you could use this for the first click and whenever it is focused

```
    ListBox l;
    l.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

and you could use whenever the area that covers the list box is clicked

```
    l.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            //
            System.out.println("you clicked me!");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Event.addEventNativePreviewHandler()` to preview the "click" event and do a `event.stopPropagation()` before the event bubbles up the ListBox (by checking the `EventTarget`).

On a related note, you can also check out `ValueListBox` which is in GWT 2.0+ which has a `ValueChangeEvent -> onValueChange()` handler (and wraps a ListBox).